# Receive data from host computer using Circuit Python on Circuit Playground Express

Tags: adafruit, micropython

I am using a Circuit Playground Express from Adafruit, and I'm programming it with Circuit Python.

I want to read data transmitted from the computer to which the Circuit Playground Express is connected via USB. Using `input()` works fine, but I would rather get the buffer of the serial instead, so that the loop would go on while there's no input. Something like `serial.read()`.

`import serial` does not work on Circuit Python, or maybe I must install something. Is there anything else I could do to read the serial buffer using Circuit Python?

Comment: By **I want to read something** do you mean you want to read characters sent by the computer that the CPE is connected to? I think you probably want to use `sys.stdin`. If you don't get anywhere with this you'll probably have more luck asking on the Micropython forum or trying any help resources available from Adafruit.

Comment: Thanks @nekomatic. Yes, I want to read something sent by the computer CPE is connected to. I'll try sys.stdin. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Apparently, as of now, this is not possible. See the complete discussion at Adafruit [here](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/231).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now *somewhat* possible!
In the January [stable release of CircuitPython 3.1.2](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/releases/tag/3.1.2) the function `serial_bytes_available` was added to the `supervisor` module.

This allows you to poll the availability of serial bytes.

For example in the CircuitPython firmware (i.e. `boot.py`) a serial echo example would be:

```
import supervisor

def serial_read():
   if supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available():
       value = input()
       print(value)
```

and ensure when you create the serial device object on the host side you set the timeout wait to be very small (i.e. 0.01).

i.e in python:

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
             '/dev/ttyACM0',
             baudrate=115200,
             timeout=0.01)

ser.write(b'HELLO from CircuitPython\n')
x = ser.readlines()
print("received: {}".format(x))
```

Answer (score 6):

Aiden's answer lead me in the right direction and I found a nice (and slightly different) example of how to use `supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available` from Adafruit here (specifically lines 89-95): https://learn.adafruit.com/AT-Hand-Raiser/circuitpython-code

A minimum working example for `code.py` that takes the input and formats a new string in the form "RX: string" is

```py
import supervisor

print("listening...")

while True:
    if supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available:
        value = input().strip()
        # Sometimes Windows sends an extra (or missing) newline - ignore them
        if value == "":
            continue
        print("RX: {}".format(value))
```

Tested on: Adafruit CircuitPython 4.1.0 on 2019-08-02; Adafruit ItsyBitsy M0 Express with samd21g18. Messages sent using the serial connection in mu-editor on macOS.

Sample output

```
main.py output:
listening...
hello!
RX: hello!
```

Answer (score 5):

I got a simple example to work based on above posts, not sure how stable or useful it is, but still posting it here:

**CircuitPython Code:**

```py
import supervisor

while True:
    if supervisor.runtime.serial_bytes_available:
        value = input().strip()
        print(f"Received: {value}\r")
```

**PC Code**

```
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)  # open serial port

command = b'hello\n\r'
print(f"Sending Command: [{command}]")
ser.write(command)     # write a string

ended = False
reply = b''

for _ in range(len(command)):
    a = ser.read() # Read the loopback chars and ignore

while True:
    a = ser.read()

    if a== b'\r':
        break

    else:
        reply += a

    time.sleep(0.01)

print(f"Reply was: [{reply}]")

ser.close()
```

```
c:\circuitpythontest>python TEST1.PY
Sending Command: [b'hello\n\r']
Reply was: [b'Received: hello']
```